how to fetch recent row less than the actual date when merged with another table in sql
Consider I have a table which has a date column that is generated everyday as given below.
table 1
ID  name    qty   date
1   abc     20   17/01/2022
1   abc     10   18/01/2022
2   def     10   24/01/2022
2   def     40   25/01/2022
2   def     67   26/01/2022

table 2
ID  name    price_dt    price
1   abc   18/01/2022    23.56
1   abc   17/01/2022    10.56
1   abc   16/01/2022    44.33
1   abc   15/01/2022    56.11
2   def   25/01/2022    2.98
2   def   26/01/2022    4.92
2   def   27/01/2022    4.88
2   def   24/01/2022    3.33
2   def   23/01/2022    8.47
2   def   22/01/2022    3.89

I'm joining the table1 with table2 and I only need the recent price_dt record that is less than the date column. This can be done my joining the 2 tables's and dropping the duplicates by sorting the price_dt DESC but the challenge is the table size is so huge and joining is not feasible. so im looking to reduce the rows in table 2 before joining.
Code that I tried in python and looking for something similar in sql


DF_A['date'] = pd.to_datetime(DF_A['date'], dayfirst=True)
DF_B['price_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(DF_B['price_dt'], dayfirst=True)

out = pd.merge_asof(DF_A.sort_values('date'), 
                   DF_B.sort_values('price_dt'), 
                   left_on='date', 
                   right_on='price_dt',
                   by=['ID','name'],
                   allow_exact_matches=False)


Expected_DF:
ID  name    qty    date     price_dt    price
1   abc    20   17/01/2022  16/01/2022  44.33
1   abc    10   18/01/2022  17/01/2022  10.56
2   def    10   24/01/2022  23/01/2022  8.47
2   def    40   25/01/2022  24/01/2022  3.33
2   def    67   26/01/2022  25/01/2022  2.98

How to obtain the above result using SQL

I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

I have, again, removed the conflicting tags. Again, please don't use conflicting tags, tag only the product you are using.

Maybe we can use this fiddle to collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/e581N6h-

Simplistic method that might be slow when table 2 is large
SELECT t1.ID, t1.name, t1.qty, t1.[date],  Max(t2.price_dt) as MaxPrice_dt,
(SELECT top 1 price FROM table2 p2 WHERE p2.ID=t1.ID AND p2.price_dt= Max(t2.price_dt)) as Price
FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.ID=T2.ID AND t1.date > t2.price_dt
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.name, t1.qty, t1.[date]
ORDER BY t1.[date] 

fiddle



ID
name
qty
date
MaxPrice_dt
Price




1
abc
20
2022-01-17
2022-01-16
44.33


1
abc
10
2022-01-18
2022-01-17
10.56


2
def
10
2022-01-24
2022-01-23
8.47


2
def
40
2022-01-25
2022-01-24
3.33


2
def
67
2022-01-26
2022-01-25
2.98




Use a temp table to minimize the number of table 2 records we must aggregate
SELECT t1.ID, t1.name, t1.[date], Price_dt, qty 
INTO #minimized  
 FROM table1 t1
 INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.ID=T2.ID AND t1.date > t2.price_dt

SELECT m.ID, m.name, m.qty, m.[date],  Max(m.price_dt) as MaxPrice_dt,
(SELECT top 1 price FROM table2 p2 WHERE p2.ID=m.ID AND p2.price_dt= Max(m.price_dt)) as Price
FROM #minimized m
GROUP BY m.ID, m.name, m.qty, m.[date]
ORDER BY m.[date] 

fiddle

Use a CTE to minimize the number of table 2 records we must aggregate
--use a CTE table to minimize the number of tabel2 records we must aggregate
WITH minimized as
(  
SELECT t1.ID, t1.name, t1.[date], Price_dt, qty 
 FROM table1 t1
 INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.ID=T2.ID AND t1.date > t2.price_dt
)
SELECT m.ID, m.name, m.qty, m.[date],  Max(m.price_dt) as MaxPrice_dt,
(SELECT top 1 price FROM table2 p2 WHERE p2.ID=m.ID AND p2.price_dt=Max(m.price_dt)) as Price 
FROM minimized m
GROUP BY m.ID, m.name, m.qty, m.[date]
ORDER BY m.[date] 

fiddle

In general terms, it looks like you have event information, like sales transactions, in one table and time series data, price changes, in another table, and you want to know what record in the time series table corresponds to events that happened in the event table.
Let's tackle this by parts. From the time series table, you need the most recent record less than (or equal to?) a given date.
This requires a max() function. So, let's start with getting the right time series record for a given date.
select *
from table2
WHERE 
    table2.price_dt in (
        select max(price_dt)
        from table2 evt_time
        where evt_time.price_dt < '24/01/2022'
    );

So far, so good. That gets us one record from the time series table based on a single point in time.
So, now the correlated subquery pattern becomes useful. Instead of the date literal, you use the date from the event table to identify which row in the times series table to return. Join table1 and table2 in the usual way.
select
    t1.ID,
    t1.name,
    t1.qty,
    t2.price as unit_price,
    t1.date 
from 
    table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on 
        t1.id = t2.id
WHERE 
    t2.price_dt in (
        select max(price_dt)
        from table2 evt_time
        where evt_time.price_dt < t1.date
    );

I get
1   abc 20  44.33   17/01/2022
1   abc 10  10.56   18/01/2022
2   def 10  8.47    24/01/2022
2   def 40  3.33    25/01/2022
2   def 67  2.98    26/01/2022

You can fiddle with the projection list as needed.

Thanks ! this query served my purpose.
